# Type 'String!' has no member 'photo'

Tags: ios, swift

I am following a tutorial on Youtube about CoreML: Real Time Camera object detection with machine learning - Swift 4 by Mr. Brian

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
```

In this line, the error says:

> Type "String" has no member 'photo'.

```
dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
```

And another error is the 'self' part. The error is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController' to expected argument type 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate!'

Below is the whole code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController,         AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // here is where we start up the camera
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo

        guard let captureDevice =
            AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else { return }

        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:
            captureDevice) else { return }
        captureSession.addInput(input)

        captureSession.startRunning()

        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session:
            captureSession)
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
        previewLayer!.frame = view.frame

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
        captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
```

Comment: Change `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. How about the first error?

Comment: Start by looking at the documentation for the `sessionPreset` property of `AVCaptureSession`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the answer for second error, for first error replace the error line with below

**SWIFT 3**

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
```

**SWIFT 4**

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
```

Comment: please switch between the two lines in your answer, swift 4 is the one above